# Como colocar um valor de uma var dentro de um item de array?

Tags: javascript, array, google-charts

Estou mexendo no `Google Charts`, mas me deparei com uma situação, e gostaria de saber se tem como fazer algo como no exemplo:

```
var numero = 45;
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Onyx', '<valor da var numero aqui>]
]);
```

Comment: Não seria isso: `var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Onyx', numero],
]);`?

Comment: Eu editei. Não tinha aquela vírgula no final ^^ mas não funcionou

Comment: Pode informar qual o erro que está apresentando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara é só passar a variavel numero dentro do vetor como o Roberto de Campos disse, o que vc tem que ver é o que `google.visualization.arrayToDataTable()` pode receber como paramêtro. Tipo pq tem um colchetes dentro do outro no método?

```js
var numero = 45;
var data = ['Onyx', numero];

alert(data);
```

Comment: Eu descobri o erro. Faltou dar um parserInt(). Mas obrigado pelo feedback, pessoal <3 resolvido